# Unhandled rejection error: StatusCodeError: 401 (Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials)

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, request, request-promise

This page shows JSON inside plain empty html/body tags. For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    **JSON DATA ***
  </body>
</html>
```

I can access that page fine doing it normally within a browser. But, when I send a request it says that my credentials are invalid (The response error is pretty much in the title).
And here is the code

```
import dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: '../logins.env' });
import rp = require('request-promise');
const jsonUrl = `http://availability.emodal.com/ImportAvailability/GetContainerInfoList?sgrdModel=%7B%22searchtext%22:%22%22,%22page%22:1,%22pageSize%22:280,%22sortBy%22:%221%22,%22sortDirection%22:%22asc%22,%22sortColumns%22:%22%22%7D`;

const authOpts = {
  uri: jsonUrl,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMODAL_id,
    pass: process.env.EMODAL_pw,
    sendImmediately: false
  },
  method: 'get'
}

rp(authOpts)
.then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
}).catch(err => { throw Error(err)});
```

I tried changing everything around. Like adding headers, or putting json: true, or changing sendImmediately to true. Nothing works. What am I not understanding or what am I doing wrong?

Here is an image showing the error in terminal:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: `Here is an image showing the error in terminal` - copy/paste the text would've been *quicker* and easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the issue is: the page of the URL can be displayed successfully after login, but the URL itself cannot be fetched directly by program.

The cause of this issue is: `auth` option of `request-promise` (inherited from module `request`) works by adding `Authorization` header in HTTP request ([document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication)). This is called [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and may not be supported by many servers. Unfortunately, in current web world, *Basic access authentication* is not popular any more (it's not secure), and it is very likely that `emodal.com` does not support it. Actually, I find a cookie in `www.emodal.com` named `ASP.NET_SessionId` which indicates the site is using SessionId cookie to authenticate user.

To fix the problem, I think the program need to *login* and save the SessionId cookie after login successfully. Then, fetch the URL resource by adding the SessionId cookie in the HTTP request header.